# Spring Framework Events

Tags: java, spring, events, asynchronous

I was reading through Spring Framework documentation and found a section on raising events in Spring using `ApplicationContext`. After reading a few paragraphs I found that Spring events are raised synchronously. Is there any way to raise asynchronous events? your help is much appreciated. I am looking something similar which would help me to complete my module.

Comment: Use a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor from spring. refer: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events

Comment: I wish it was there in year 2009. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest asynchronous `ApplicationListener`:

Publisher:

```
@Autowired
private SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster simpleApplicationEventMulticaster;

@Autowired
private AsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor;

// ...

simpleApplicationEventMulticaster.setTaskExecutor(asyncTaskExecutor);

// ...

ApplicationEvent event = new ApplicationEvent("");
simpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(event);
```

Listener:

```
@Component
static class MyListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> 
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
         // do stuff, typically check event subclass (instanceof) to know which action to perform
    }
}
```

You should subclass `ApplicationEvent` with your specific events. You can configure `SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster` and its `taskExecutor` in an XML file.

You might want to implement `ApplicationEventPublisherAware` in your listener class and pass a source object (instead of empty string) in the event constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative notification strategies can be achieved by implementing `ApplicationEventMulticaster` (see [Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ApplicationEventMulticaster.html)) and its underlying (helper) class hierarchy. Typically you use either a JMS based notification mechanism (as David already suggested) or attach to Spring's `TaskExecuter` abstraction (see [Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html)).

Answer (score 2):

Spring itself (AFAIK) work synchronously, but what you can do is to create your own ApplicationListener proxy - a class that implements this interface but instead of handling the event it just delegates it by sending to another (or new) thread, sending JMS message, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this override the ApplicationEventMulticaster bean in resources.groovy so that it uses a thread pool:

Some thing like this worked for me, i.e. I used

```
import java.util.concurrent.*
import org.springframework.context.event.*

beans = {
    applicationEventMulticaster(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster) {
        taskExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
    }
}
```