# Spring application listeners instead of threads

Tags: spring

Spring Provides e Application Listeners to handle Application Events. I want to get rid  of my Thread classes and use these listeners for event handling  .Any hint to start?Can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please consider that ApplicationListener notification is *synchronous* by default thus it's not direct replacement for any asynchronous solution based on threads that you might have. On the other hand it's possible to change default strategy of events delivery to make it asynchronous (but it still will require some coding). I would start straight from Spring [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-functionality-events) :)

Answer (score 4):

You can extend ApplicationEvent for your custom event and implement ApplicationListener to handle it. These events are synchronous (blocking).

Or you can make use of AsyncTaskExecutor to turn them asynchronous.

You can find an example of the later in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15562885/1297812).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @zessx: I agree. But, being an internal link, if it becomes dead most probably this page will be too. I edit and add info, cheers.