# Creating asynchronous events in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was looking at using spring 3.1 for publishing events and using listeners to consume these events. however I have read that these events are synchronous, is it possible to make them asynchronous, maybe use the @async annotation?

Im really looking at creating an event driven architecture in Java/Spring - publishing and consuming events, would you think Spring/Java would suffice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Framework Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382633/spring-framework-events)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it will be perfect to use [Spring integration.](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) which gives a different kinds of messaging solutions.

Here is a little explanation about
[Event-Driven Consumer:](http://www.eaipatterns.com/EventDrivenConsumer.html)

And here is an example in Spring integration that is relevant to your needs:

1. [Messaging Endpoints](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.M3/spring-integration-reference/html/endpoint.html)
2. [some more examples](http://www.springbyexample.org/static/1.2/html/simple-spring-integration-code-example.html)

Good luck!

Comment: looked at spring integration, seemed a little heavy weight for what i wanted to do.. all I have is one class publishing events and at most two classes listening to them. and all classes are in the same web app.

Comment: OK, so it doesn't looks like it is a problem implementing it yourself. the what do you need some kind of scheduling mechanism that will publish the events?

Comment: You can create a bean named applicationEventMulticaster (SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster) in the ApplicationContext and set the TaskExecutor to SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor. This will allow asynchronous event dispatching with-in spring.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the [Spring Reactor](http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/13/reactor-a-foundation-for-asynchronous-applications-on-the-jvm) project?

Here's an excerpt:

> **What is Reactor good for?**
>
> While you can make Reactor do a lot of things because of its inherent
>   flexibility, it’s really designed to be a foundational framework for
>   applications that need high throughput when performing reasonably
>   small chunks of stateless, asynchronous processing. The sheer volume
>   of non-human-generated data in modern applications can easily overtake
>   a traditional single-threaded, blocking design model. From mobile
>   applications that generate streams of location information to
>   computerized manufacturing machines that send out vast amounts of
>   geometric data to big data applications mining real-time logs to
>   generate business metrics: modern data-driven applications demand
>   better resource utilization and higher throughput than a traditional
>   imperative, blocking application can usually provide.

Comment: I'm using spring 5. It has both reactor and spring-events. Which one should someone use?